# How to mount root filesystem read-only - 16.04

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, data-recovery, read-only

In the past when I entered recovery-mode, the root filesystem was read-only and that was perfectly fine.

But now. after pressing enter at the prompt to drop to shell, it is mounted read-write. It is cumbersome to remount as read-only because many processes are accessing files on it.

I need root filesystem read-only when I am in recovery mode. How can I boot into recovery mode and have it read-only?

Comment: This is still an issue as of 18.04.3 in 2020..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At initrd stage the root fs is in **ro** mode. And after systemd starts and remounts root fs into **rw** mode. I don't know guts of systemd well. So I tell you how to stop booting right before systemd.
You need to add this line:

```
break=init
```

to the end of the kernel parameters. You'll get a command line and the root fs will be in **ro** mode.

Comment: This causes me to enter to initramfs shell which is fine for my purposes. Before I mark is correct, I will wait if somebody comes up with a solution which brings back original recovery console functionality with read-only root partition. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This happens because systemd (specifically, systemd-remount-fs.service) by design ignores your kernel parameter of `ro`. Whether this is a good or harebrained design is a matter of opinion, but for an objective workaround, you can add `systemd.mask=systemd-remount-fs.service` to your kernel parameters in grub, along with `ro`:

```
... systemd.mask=systemd-remount-fs.service ro
```